# How to Produce the Anarchy Symbol

Tags: characters

I was wondering if it's possible to produce the anarchy symbol (the circled 'A') in LaTeX.  I tried googling "latex anarchist" and got nothing but merchandise and porn, and while I'm not complaining, I *also* wanted the anarchy symbol.

Comment: You're referring to [this symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchist_symbolism#mediaviewer/File:Anarchy-symbol.svg)?

Comment: @Werner Yes, really I'll take just about any of them, but the circled 'A', usually with an extra-long horizontal bar, is what I was searching for.

Comment: Ideally the question should be specific. So, [pick one of the symbols from a Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=anarchy+symbol&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=WNMgVIDALZXsoAT064DIAw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ) and include it in your post.

Comment: You wouldn't mean this one, by chance ;^) ?: http://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2014/04/02/ab2c6e9d-f609-4a8c-9da5-929eb81981bc/resize/770x578/4f37990c1346a0976bed41a53bf0bf9d/windows.jpg

Comment: By "produce" you mean "draw" it?  You can of course scale an `.svg` image(, convert it,) and include it via the `graphicx` package.

Comment: From marvosym there is \CircledA according to The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the Unicode code points for anarchic symbols. But the circled A is not at all pleasant. Maybe you have to download some [cooler font...](http://www.fontspace.com/category/anarchy). I posted these just so you can see what exists and how to use it.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{#1 & \setmainfont{#1}\symbol{"24B6} & \setmainfont{#1}\symbol{"2605} & \setmainfont{#1}\symbol{"2691}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}\toprule
        Font& A & Black Star & Black Flag\\\midrule
        \test{Symbola.ttf}\\
        \test{Quivira.otf}\\
        \test{Xits-regular.otf}\\
        \test{Code2000.ttf}\\
        \test{DejaVuSans.ttf}\\
        Font Awesome&&&\faFlag\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of TeX code above: anarchist symbols from various fonts]

---

From Mr. Kormylo's comment:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}
\CircledA
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of TeX code above: a circled A]

---

And finally, here is the [symbol from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchist_symbolism) (I enlarged the horizontal bar for you). As your question was how to *produce* the anarchy symbol, I will explain that a bit. You download an SVG file from somewhere (like the one provided by Wikipedia) and open it in Inkscape. You will need to install the add-on [`inkscape2tikz`](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/). In Inkscape you choose

> Extensions -> Export -> Export to TikZ Path.

The rest should be clear.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.5pt, x=0.5pt,yscale=-1]
\path[cm={{0.0,-1.0,1.0,0.0,(0.0,0.0)}},fill=black,rounded corners=0.0000cm]
(-360.0000,49.3220) rectangle (-296.0000,557.6695);
\path[fill=black] (300.0000,0.0000) .. controls (135.0000,0.0000) and
(0.0000,135.0000) .. (0.0000,300.0000) .. controls (0.0000,465.0000) and
(135.0000,600.0000) .. (300.0000,600.0000) .. controls (465.0000,600.0000) and
(600.0000,465.0000) .. (600.0000,300.0000) .. controls (600.0000,135.0000) and
(465.0000,0.0000) .. (300.0000,0.0000) -- cycle(300.0000,64.0000) .. controls
(431.0000,64.0000) and (536.0000,169.0000) .. (536.0000,300.0000) .. controls
(536.0000,431.0000) and (431.0000,536.0000) .. (300.0000,536.0000) .. controls
(169.0000,536.0000) and (64.0000,431.0000) .. (64.0000,300.0000) .. controls
(64.0000,169.0000) and (169.0000,64.0000) .. (300.0000,64.0000) -- cycle;
\path[cm={{-0.90631,-0.42262,0.42262,-0.90631,(0.0,0.0)}},fill=black,rounded
corners=0.0000cm] (-328.0631,-404.1956) rectangle (-264.0631,95.8044);
\path[cm={{-0.90631,0.42262,-0.42262,-0.90631,(0.0,0.0)}},fill=black,rounded
corners=0.0000cm] (-279.6533,-657.7666) rectangle (-215.6533,-157.7666);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of TeX code above: the Anarchist symbol]

Comment: Why the rollback? I fixed your grammar, improved accessibility by adding image descriptions, and made sundry other improvements to your post. Why did you roll that back?

Comment: @TRiG Hi, the problem was the main "improvement" 'pleasant' to 'present' which was not correct. As you put this change as description to your edit, I had to roll back to get rid of it. Sorry for the other changes you made (but they have just been of minor nature). Feel free to edit again.

Answer (score 40):

Fancy anarchy with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{mydeco/.style={decoration={random steps,segment length=.6,amplitude=.5},decorate,line cap=round}}

\tikzset{anarchy/.pic={
    \draw[ultra thick,mydeco,decorate,red,fill=red](0,0)--(1,.3)--cycle;
    \draw[ultra thick,mydeco,red,fill=red](.2,-.3)--(.5,.7)--cycle;
    \draw[ultra thick,mydeco,red,fill=red](.5,.7)--(.8,-.3)--cycle;
    \draw[red,ultra thick,line cap=round,mydeco](.5,.15) circle(.4);
}}

\begin{document}
Some real \tikz\pic{anarchy};narchy
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also in a more scalable fashion (doesn't scale to `\tiny`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,positioning}

\tikzset{mydeco/.style={decoration={random steps,segment length=.08em,amplitude=.05em},decorate,line cap=round}}

\tikzset{anarchy/.pic={
    \draw[line width=.1em,mydeco,decorate,red,fill=red](0em,0em)--(1.2em,.3em)--cycle;
    \draw[line width=.1em,mydeco,red,fill=red](.2em,-.3em)--(.5em,.7em)--cycle;
    \draw[line width=.1em,mydeco,red,fill=red](.5em,.7em)--(.8em,-.3em)--cycle;
    \draw[line width=.1em,red,line cap=round,mydeco](.5em,.2em) circle(.6em);
}}

\newcommand{\anarchy}{\tikz\pic{anarchy};}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize Some real \anarchy{}narchy

\footnotesize Some real \anarchy{}narchy

\small Some real \anarchy{}narchy

\normalsize Some real \anarchy{}narchy

\large Some real \anarchy{}narchy
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I was also working in a very similar idea, but you were faster

Answer (score 14):

A variant with `tikz` with longer horizontal bar:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\AnarchySymbol}[1][50pt]{%
  \tikz[
    x=\dimexpr(#1)\relax,
    y=\dimexpr(#1)\relax,
    radius=\dimexpr(#1)\relax,
    line width=\dimexpr.2\dimexpr(#1)\relax\relax,
  ]
  \draw
    circle []
    (90:1) -- (235:1)
    (90:1) -- (305:1)
    (185:1) -- (-5:1)
  ;%
}

\begin{document}
  \AnarchySymbol
\end{document}
```

> [image: Anarchy symbol]

Comment: I think that's the old logo from Marvel's Avengers

Comment: @NewAlexandria I do not know about "old". The [Symbol from Marvel's The Avengers logo](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Symbol_from_Marvel%27s_The_Avengers_logo.svg) is different, e.g. it contains a horizontal arrow.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a scalable TikZ variant which I drew as part of a larger project:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  anarchy/.pic={%
        \draw [line width=.1*#1, {Round Cap[length=.025*#1]}-{Round Cap[length=.025*#1]}, pic actions] (-.5*#1,-.1*#1) -- (.6*#1,.1*#1);
        \draw [line width=.1*#1, line join=bevel, {Round Cap[length=.025*#1]}-{Round Cap[length=.025*#1]}, pic actions] (-.25*#1,-.475*#1) -- (0,.5*#1) coordinate (-vertex) -- (.35*#1,-.525*#1);
        \node  [draw, line width=.1*#1, anchor=center, align=center, pic actions] at (0,0) [circle through={($(-vertex) + (-.15*#1,-.125*#1)$)}] {};
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [red] {anarchy={50pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: anarchy in red]

Hence you can, if you wish, say

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path  pic [red!50!black] {anarchy={25pt}} -- ++(30pt,0) pic [red] {anarchy=50pt} -- ++(60pt,0) pic [black] {anarchy={75pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to obtain

[image: several anarchies]

Comment: Cool--can it have Doom Paul in it?